# Partial limits of sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm studying for a test in Calc I, and one of the practice problems is to "find a sequence with exactly 3 partial limits" and "find a sequence with an unlimited number of partial limits."

I have answers, they are both examples of such cases. 
I don't understand however how I can systematically create such a sequence.

Comment: for finitely many limiting values $a_1,...,a_n$ use the sequence
$a_1,...,a_n,a_1,...,a_n,a_1,...,a_n,...$ ie just repeat the values over and over.  (i assume by partial limit you mean there exists a subsequence converging to that value)

Comment: $a_1,a_1,a_2,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,\dots$

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that. Yes I'm referring to limits of sub-sequences.

Comment: yoyo answered the first. 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,... Can converge to 1, 2, or 3. Gerry gave an example for your second question.

Comment: @yoyo for a private case or the general case, how would you prove this is indeed the number of partial limits? (sorry for coming back to such an old question, but I got it as related when about to ask a similar question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chaz answered part of your question.  Here's one with infinitely many partial limits:
$$
1, \underbrace{1,2}, \underbrace{1,2,3}, \underbrace{1,2,3,4},\underbrace{1,2,3,4,5},\ldots .
$$

Here's another:
$$
\underbrace{\frac12}, \underbrace{\frac13,\frac23},\underbrace{\frac14,\frac24,\frac34},\underbrace{\frac15,\frac25,\frac35,\frac45},\ldots.
$$
Every number between $0$ and $1$ (inclusive) is a partial limit of this sequence.